# Trivialising homeomorphisms for a principal $G$-bundle as $G$-space morphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, topological-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $P$ by a principal $G$-fibre bundle over a locally-compact Hausdorff space $X$. Denote by
$$
h: U \times G \to P|_{U} 
$$
a trivialising homeomorphism for a trivialising open set $U \subseteq X$. Now the domain and range of $h$ are both $G$-spaces in an obvious way. Is $h$ a morphism of $G$-spaces? If so why? If true and not evident, I would be grateful for a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which definitions you use, but this is more or less true by definition. I suppose you would start by requiring the transition functions between the trivializations to be given by left multiplications in the group. Then you define the principal right action on $P$ by requiring that in the trivialization it is given by multiplication from the right in $G$. But this exactly means that the map $h$ you consider is $G$-equvariant for $(x,g)\cdot h:=(x,gh)$ and the principal right action on $P|_U$.

Comment: @AC: If $\alpha : G \to G$ is an automorphism of $G$ then why isn't $h' : U \times G \to P|_U$ given by $h'(u, g) = h(u, \alpha(g))$ a perfectly reasonable chart map? In that case if the map $h$ is as above, we have $h'(u,g)s = h(u, \alpha(g))s = h(u, \alpha(g)s) = h'(u, g \alpha^{-1}(s))$.
or do you just avoid choosing h that way?

Comment: As I said, I don't know how you choose definitions. Usually you start from an atlas for which the transition functions are given by left multiplications. Then you define the principal right action as I indicated and then you define principal bundle charts by equivariancy with respect to principal right action and multiplication from the right on $G$. So $h'$ is not a principal bundle chart by definition. (Or do you have a different meaning of "principal bundle chart" in mind?)

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the extra explanation!